# (opendj-ldap-sdk-2.6.0) bind method parameter - password char [ ]

Tags: java, ldap, openldap, opendj, forgerock

I'm using opendj-ldap-sdk-2.6.0 jar library to search LDAP entry. 
I am following the guide. 
(https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/2.6/dev-guide/#chap-using-the-sdk)

**source code :**

```
import org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.Connection;
import org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.LDAPConnectionFactory;
import org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.SearchScope;
import org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.responses.SearchResultEntry;
import org.forgerock.opendj.ldap.responses.SearchResultReference;
import org.forgerock.opendj.ldif.ConnectionEntryReader;
import org.forgerock.opendj.ldif.LDIFEntryWriter;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final LDIFEntryWriter writer = new LDIFEntryWriter(System.out);
    Connection connection = null; 

    try { 
        final LDAPConnectionFactory factory = new LDAPConnectionFactory("localhost",389);

        connection = factory.getConnection();
        connection.bind("cn = Directory Mangager", password );
        // password is just an example of the password. 

        final ConnectionEntryReader reader = connection.search("dc=example,dc=com", SearchScope.WHOLE_SUBTREE,"(uid=bjensen)","*");
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            if(reader.isEntry()) {
                final SearchResultEntry entry = reader.readEntry();
                writer.writeComment("Search result entry:" + entry.getName().toString());
                writer.writeEntry(entry);
            } else {
                final SearchResultReference ref = reader.readReference();
                writer.writeComment("Search result reference:" + ref.getURIs().toString());
            }
        }
        writer.flush();
    } catch (final Exception e) { 
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } finally { 
        if (connection !=null) { 
            connection.close(); 
        }
    }
}
```

> > connection.bind("cn = Directory Mangager", password );

I'm getting a red line at this line under password because the parameter has to be 'char []'.
I captured Bind method in the below.

[image]

**If my password is 1234,  how can I change that into char [] type?**

Comment: You're missing a call from factory to obtain a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a call from factory to obtain a connection.

```
  connection = factory.getConnection();
  connection.bind("cn = Directory Mangager", password );
```

Comment: Even with that, it doesn't solve my question. I keep getting the red line under password, saying its char value or something.  I put ' around instead of " (String). still doesn't work.

Comment: In your code extract, the variable password is not defined. It should be a `char[]` and the value should be a valid UTF-8 set of characters.

Comment: thank you. password wasn't a variable. according to the manual, I'm supposed to put my password there. I put 'password[ there as an example of password.  I saw the description char[ ] part, but couldn't understand :(.  If my password is 1234 , how can I make that into char [ ] type?

Comment: Hey thank you for your tips. With your help, I figured it out. Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

> connection.bind("cn=Directory Manager", "yourpassword".toCharArray() );

You can use **toCharArray()**

Also, as Ludovic Poitou mentioned above, you need to use
**connection = factory.getConnection();** with the bind method. 
The guide says if you are not using anonymous search, use the bind method, but you gotta use them both.  (I misunderstood the guide)

Comment: Well, this is properly documented in the right section: https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/opendj/2.6/dev-guide/#chap-authenticating